# Bash Wildcard Partial Match Directory

Tags: bash, wildcards

I have this bash script which is trying to find a directory that partially changes on peoples systems.

```
cd "$HOMEDIR/AppData/Local/GitHub/PortableGit"*"/bin"
```

Yet this does not seem to work - it just take the string literal.

Is there an easy to make it expand correctly?

Edit:

Okay this is weird it works some of the time.

When I do this:

```
GIT_DIR=$HOMEDIR/AppData/Local/GitHub/PortableGit*/bin
eval GIT_DIR_PASS=$GIT_DIR
echo $GIT_DIR_PASS
```

I get the correct information out

but when I try to assign $GIT_DIR_PASS to another variable I get the string literal version.

Comment: It not completely clear to me what you want. Did you try without all the quotes `"`?

Comment: It works if that glob matches something. `$HOME` is usually the home directory. Are you setting `$HOMEDIR` manually?

Comment: I am setting the home directory manually. But I always get this error message. AppData/Local/GitHub/PortableGit*/bin : No such file or directory

Answer (score 8):

> ```
> GIT_DIR=$HOMEDIR/AppData/Local/GitHub/PortableGit*/bin
> ```

Above the wildcard is not expanded, because you're assigning to a scalar variable which can only contain **one** string, so no word splitting or filename generation take place there.

> ```
> eval GIT_DIR_PASS=$GIT_DIR
> ```

Here, it's a an argument to a simple command, so wildcards are expanded but they would be expanded to files whose path is `"GIT_DIR_PATH=..."`.

> ```
> echo $GIT_DIR_PASS
> ```

Here the wildcards are expanded. You're not printing the content of the variable, but the list of arguments that result from the expansion since the variable is not quoted.

You'd want:

```
set -- "$HOMEDIR"/AppData/Local/GitHub/PortableGit*/bin
```

That is expand that pattern into the list of matching files and assign them to `$1`, `$2`...

```
GIT_DIR=$1
```

Pick the first one.

Comment: +1. I like the sugguestion to use `set`. Maybe you should have described a way to process its results, too. I still think Ley is intending something like `for GIT_DIR in $*; do cd $GIT_DIR; dostuff; cd ~; done`. Thank you for your informative answer.

Comment: @J.Katzwinkel Do not use `$*` (or even `"$*"`), it mangles your arguments into one (and will have wordsplitting performed on them as well if you don't quote it). Use `"$@"` instead, which preserves the arguments intact.

Comment: Good point! I'm used not to having whitespace in file names, so I didn't think of word splitting. But to be honest, even on paths containing spaces, it doesn't really make a difference if I use `$*` or `$@`, quoted or not. We talking `bash` here?

Comment: @J.Katzwinkel Yes, we're talking bash, and yes it matters, as Chris Down said. `$*` and `$@` will split all arguments by whitespace, so if `$1` is `a b` and `$2` is `c`, both will loop over `a`, `b`, and `c`; `"$*"` will loop over `a b c` (as a single string), but `"$@"` will correctly loop over `a b` and `c`. If you don't believe us, I suggest you open a terminal and try it out.

Comment: Regardless, to go a step further, if you're looping over the positional variables (`$1`, `$2`, etc.), you don't even need the `in` part: `for GIT_DIR; do cd $GIT_DIR; do_stuff; done`.

Comment: @Kevin, thank you for making this clear. Of course I checked on the behaviour of all terms discussed before I expressed my doubts, but apparently not attentively enugh. Now that you encouraged me to double-check, I found the embarassing mistake I made earlier and am now entirely convinced. Thanks for the help of both of you! I will happy to follow your advise in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [these examples](http://www.tuxfiles.org/linuxhelp/wildcards.html) to get a feeling for how to use wildcards in `bash`. Also, forget about the `eval` stuff.

A glob that would match all directories named `/bin/` that are direct subdirectories of any direct subdirectory of `.../PortableGit/`:

```
HOMEDIR=/home/$USER
ls "$HOMEDIR/AppData/Local/GitHub/PortableGit/"*"/bin"
```

I think `cd` is your problem. What exactly do you expect it to do? If there is more than one directory matching your expression, it would be fruitless to call it that way, because `cd` will end up in the first matching directory, whatever you are planning on doing in there. If you want to sequentially enter directories do do stuff in them, then performing a loop over a conforming `find` output would seem more appropriate.

There is a similar question on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6665466/bash-script-with-wildcards).

Comment: There is no reason to avoid quotes in glob expressions. Pathname Expansion is done after word splitting so the special chars "don't see" the quotes at all.

Comment: Thank you for sharing that detail, I modified my answer to be of a less absolute tone. _But_: neither _is there a reason_ to have quotes involved in glob expressions. If the quotes were around the wildcard, nothing would be expanded at all. This is why I kinda wanted to have them out of the way in this case.

Comment: You are even forced to use quotes if the glob expression contains metacharacters (like space). Do we know what $HOMEDIR looks like...

Comment: You got me again. I edited accordingly and drew back even further. I hope you'll show the mercy of not proving me wrong another time.

Comment: Your decision how much you want to learn today. :-) If you decide to learn more then I would point you at the fact that * doesn't match / so that your "any subdirectory" has to be understood as "any direct subdirectory". Maybe you meant that but I find the wording ambigious.

Comment: Yes, that is what I wanted, however could't, express in my posting. Obviously it's time for me to wish my keyboard a goodnight for today. Thank you very much. Appreciate your tutoring!